# How to add a fragment before a query param in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a URL http://localhost:8080/test?filter=abc

I have to route to same component , but I want to add a fragment identifier after the path param 'test' after routing.

http://localhost:8080/test#retest?filter=abc

Please help.

Comment: what is the use case for this ?

Comment: Based on the fragment identifier, i have to perform some processing in my component. For example : When somebody hits the URL with http://localhost:8080/test#retest?filter=abc, I will identify that it contains 'reset' and based on that will perform some operation

Comment: https://www.geekstrick.com/fragment-url-in-angular-8/ check this, if this helps u